# PCIe DMA Driver for Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, fpga

I am currently working on a Virtex 7 FPGA . I am trying to install the driver for the PCIe DMA driver for linux . But it is giving me the following error :

**error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_enable_msix’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]**

Can someone help me with this error ?

Comment: Please post the text of the error rather than an image. Your post is unusable by those users with mobile devices or behind many corporate proxies. It's also difficult to read even on a typical laptop display..

Comment: error: implicit declaration of function  ‘pci_enable_msix’ . This is the error I receive.

Comment: The entire error message, in the question itself instead of the image. Posting it in a comment does absolutely nothing to address the issues I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Linux cross reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com) is a very good resource for this kind of problem, because you can explore the change in API over kernel version.

Answer (score 2):

Linux 4.8 replaced it with `pci_enable_msix_range`. You can fix it like this:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(4,8,0)
        rc = pci_enable_msix(pdev, lro->entry, req_nvec);
#else
        rc = pci_enable_msix_range(pdev, lro->entry, req_nvec, req_nvec);
#endif
```

Comment: And you missed even more updates to this API, nowadays the both you mentioned are obsolete, one needs to call `pci_alloc_irq_vectors()` (IIRC the name of the call).